# Error installing requirements-test.txt on windows

Tags: python, django, pip, pypi

I was trying to install "requirements-test.txt" after installing "requirements.txt" but it showed me errors:

### 1.ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

### 2.ERROR: Failed building wheel for requirements-test.txt

Can some one please help me on how to get rid of these errors.

The screenshot of error screen is attached underneath:
[Error screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FarNy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `-r` to install from a requirements file

```
pip install -r requirements-test.txt
```

Comment: I tried this command but its showing another error,                                         
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements-test.txt'

Comment: Does `requirements-test.txt` exist in the directory where you are running the command?

Comment: oh yeah it was the directory error..thank you